# About Panel Data Analysis

Tags: residuals

My Study is the impact of Ebanking on Financial Performance of Public and Private sector banks in India and I am taking ROA, NIM as dependent variable and ATM Transactions, POS transactions, NEFT Inward Transactions, RTGS inward Transactions, ATM, Debit and Credit Cards as independent variables.
Through, Hausman test, i found that fixed effect model is valid for my study but in Residual Diagnostic, no assumption is met despite doing panel unit root test so please suggest me what should i do?